# Creating a sparse matrix from csv file data

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

Data in the csv file is of the format ("user_id", "group_id", "group_value").
"group_id" ranges from 0 to 100.

For a given user_id, it may be possible that group_value for a particular group_id is not available.

I want to create a sparse matrix representation of the above data. ("group_id_0", "group_id_1", ... , "group_id_100")

What is the best way to achieve this in Python?

**Edit**: Data is too big to iterate over.

Comment: You could use the Scikit-Learn [One hot encoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html)

Comment: You have to first map the ids onto unique integers.  The dimensions of a sparse matrix are simply indexed as 0,1,2,....  No fancy labels.  From your description the `group_id` already fits with a sparse matrix with 101 columns.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this with pandas.

**Update 08.08.2018:**

As noticed by Can Kavaklıoğlu, `as_matrix()` is deprecated as of pandas version 0.23.0. Changed to `values`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('csv_file.csv', names=['user_id', 'group_id', 'group_value'])
df = df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='group_id', values='group_value')
mat = df.values
```

Comment: Last line has an extra close parentheses. Also pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix() was deprecated since 0.23.0. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.as_matrix.html#pandas-dataframe-as-matrix